# Tratar exceção ao fazer replace de string via JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

Eu criei uma função simples em JavaScript para substituir uma string qualquer por um link dentro de uma área no meu html. Até então eu passo alguns parâmetros e essa função faz um replace no meu html e inseri os links como desejado.

Porem agora estou precisando tratar alguns casos e não consegui pensar numa forma simples de resolver.

Basicamente os casos que preciso tratar é:

- Não converter a string em link quando estiver dentro de outro
  link.
- Não converter a string em link quando estiver como valor de um
  atributo das tags.

O html que realizo o find e replace, recebo assim:

```
<p><a class="btn" href="http://www.google.com.br/">Mecanismo de Busca</a>, loren ipsun dolor loren Google.</p>
<p>Loren ipsun dolor loren Google, loren ipsun dolor <span>Loren</span>, <b>Google</b>.</p>
<p>Acesse o <a class="btn" href="http://www.google.com.br/" title="Acesse o Google">Google</a></p>
```

Minha função é esta:

```
var jsLib = {
    replaceToHref: function (word, url, target) {
        var wordWithTag = '<a href="' + url + '" title="' + word + '" target="' + target + '">' + word + '</a>'
        var content = document.getElementById('page-content-replace');

        var result = content.innerHTML.replace(new RegExp("(\\s|\\.|\\-|^|;|\\!|\\?|\\(|\\)|\\:|\\\\)(" + word + ")(\\s|\\.|\\-|^|;|\\!|\\?|\\(|\\)|\\:|\\\\)", "g"), "$1" + wordWithTag + "$3");

        content.innerHTML = result;
    }
};
```

Considerando o html recebido e a função, ao executar e passar o link e a palavra Google, ele troca em todos os lugares, porem isto quebra o html.

Alguma sugestão de como resolver isto?

Comment: tem como por exemplo dos casos que você não quer converter?

Comment: é possível criar uma array com as posições de tudo o que você quer mudar, e criar uma outra array com as posições de tudo o que não deve ser mudado, e validar ao fazer o replace

Answer (score 1):

Fiz um exemplo com comentários.

A lógica é simples...

1. Vc salva as tags existentes em um array separado
2. Substituir todos "word" por "wordWithTag"
3. Voltar com a tags pré-existentes para o lugar

Para reservar o espaço de cada tag original, eu usei a string: `{{PLACEHOLDER_TO_OLDS_TAGS_A}}`

```js
var target = '<p><a class="btn" href="http://www.google.com.br!!!!!!/">Mecanismo de Busca</a>, loren ipsun dolor loren Google.</p>'
+ '<p>Loren ipsun dolor loren Google, loren ipsun dolor <span>Loren</span>, <b>Google</b>.</p>'
+ '<p>Acesse o <a class="btn" href="http://www.google.com.br/" title="Acesse o Google">Google</a></p>';



function replaceToHref(word, url, target){
        //Espaço o reservado para as as tags "a" já existentes
        var placeHolder = '{{PLACEHOLDER_TO_OLDS_TAGS_A}}';
        //Regex para a tag "a"
        var matchTagA = /<a.*?>.*?<\/a>/g;


        //Cria a tag
        var wordWithTag = '<a href="' + url + '" title="' + word + '">' + word + '</a>\n';
        //Escapa string a ser buscada
        var wordEscaped = word.replace(/[\-\[\]\/\{\}\(\)\*\+\?\.\\\^\$\|]/g, "\\$&");

        //Cria um array com todos os "a" já existentes
        var oldLinks = target.match(matchTagA);
        //Remove todas as tags "a"
        var targetWithoutTagA = target.replace(matchTagA,placeHolder);
        // Substitui todas as ocorrências da palavra pela tag
        var newTarget = targetWithoutTagA.replace(new RegExp(wordEscaped, 'gi'), wordWithTag);

        //Verifica se "oldLink" é um array e se tem algo, pois pode ser que o target não tenha nenhuma tag "a"
        if(Array.isArray(oldLinks) && oldLinks.length){
                //Dá um replace em uma ocorrência por vez coincidindo com o a posição anterior
                for(var i = 0;i < oldLinks.length; i++){
                        newTarget = newTarget.replace(placeHolder,oldLinks[i]);
                }
        }

        return newTarget;
}

console.log(replaceToHref('google','abc',target));
```